# Can an ISP or webpage block me from accessing it if I'm sending too many requests?

Tags: denial-of-service

I visit webpage where there is a comment section. 
These comments have a number of likes/dislikes as 2 numbers.
If I vote, a cookie is created and I can't vote again (but I can if I delete my cookies, but it doesn't matter). It is therefore possible to automate this voting by sending voting requests with burp suite.

Can this vote "spamming" be considered as a DOS attack or something like that?
I'm sending too many requests in a short period of time. Can they block me, or call my ISP to block me? Is it possible? or will they care?

The same with password guessing using burp suite.
I know that they can identify me by my IP address, but can they punish me or something for sending and making too much traffic?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with burp. Many automated processes and proxies could do what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

Your ISP could block you if they wanted to, but they probably wouldn't. If your ISP suspected you were doing illegal activity, they would more likely simply disable your service completely and report you to the proper authorites.

The website you are visiting can block you too, but whether they will is dependent on their rules and configuration. If your requests are frequent enough, you will probably be blocked by a firewall before you even get to the website.

If the website detects what you are doing, the action they take would be up to them, and would probably depend on the severity of your actions. You already know that **what you are doing is morally wrong at best, and illegal at worst.** If the votes could sway public opinion for an election, or if prizes/money can be won based on vote counts, then this is definitely illegal. Even if it's just for fun and the votes mean nothing, if you mess up and cause a DOS attack because the site doesn't have adequate protections in place, that is illegal as well.

The best advice I could provide is don't do it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the moral and legal ramifications. I just wanted to add that at the day someone pays for these resources. So if they are on shared hosting or cloud hosting plan someone is paying for your spam. This cost could be mere pennies to several thousand dollars. It is definitely an uncool thing to do especially if it is a smaller outfit or organization running this site.

Comment: i know all the moral thing behind
voting can be added "llegally" just with browser and F5 too
is it too illegal?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a right to visit and use a website. The website owner can block you from using their services for any reason they want.

The same applies to your ISP. They are a private company, and they can feely decide if they want to make business with you or not. Read the contract you made with them to see under which conditions they can terminate the contract.